# my first FATALEXCEPTION.The java is not working apparently

Tags: java, android-studio

Hello and thank you for reading this.
            I am trying to build an app that measures besides the score,also the score for goal attempts and for fouls as well.Apparently the Java does not agree with me.
            This is the error that leaves me speechless:
 *          *THE JAVA CODE**

```
        package com.example.android.courtcounter;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import com.example.android.soccercounter.R;
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        int scoreTeamA = 0;
        int scoreTeamB = 0;
        int FoulForTeamA = 0;
        int FoulForTeamB = 0;
        int ShotOnGoalForTeamA = 0;
        int ShotOnGoalForTeamB = 0;
        /**
         * Displays the given score for Team A.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

         /**
         * Displays the given score for Team A.
         */
        public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
            scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        }

        /**
         * 1.0-Displays the FOUL score for Team A.
         */
        public void displayFoulScoreForTeamA(int foulForTeamA) {
            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_foul_score);
            scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(foulForTeamA));
        }
        /**
         * 1.0-Displays the goal attempt score for Team A.
         */
        public void displayGoalAttemptForTeamA(int shotOnGoalForTeamA) {
            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_goal_attempt_score);
            scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(shotOnGoalForTeamA));
        }

        /**
         * Displays the given score for Team B.
         */
        public void displayForTeamB(int foulForTeamB) {
            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
            scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(foulForTeamB));
        }
        /**
         * 1.0-Displays the given FOUL score for Team B.
         * Probably i have to modify the int score to int foul score,but I haven't located.
         */
        public void displayFoulScoreForTeamB(int foulForTeamB) {
            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_foul_score);
            scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(foulForTeamB));
        }

        /**
         * 1.0-Displays the goal attempt score for Team B.
         */
        public void displayGoalAttemptForTeamB(int shotOnGoalForTeamB) {
            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_goal_attempt_score);
            scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(shotOnGoalForTeamB));
        }

        /**
         * Increase the score for Team A by 1 point.
         */
        public void addOneForTeamA(View v) {
            scoreTeamA=scoreTeamA + 1;
            displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        }
        /**
         * 1.0-Increase the FOUL score for Team A by 1 point.
         * Maybe I should modify this whole addFoul,i still do not get the add part,is it mandatory?
         */
        public void addFoulForTeamA(View v) {
            FoulForTeamA=FoulForTeamA + 1;
            displayForTeamA(FoulForTeamA);
        }

        /**
         * Increase the score for Team B by 1 point.
         */
        public void addOneForTeamB(View v) {
            scoreTeamB=scoreTeamB + 1;
            displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
        }
        /**
         * 1.0-Increase the FOUL score for Team B by 1 point.
         * Maybe I should modify this whole addFoul,i still do not get the add part,is it mandatory?
         */
        public void addFoulForTeamB(View v) {
            FoulForTeamB=FoulForTeamB + 1;
            displayForTeamB(FoulForTeamB);
        }





        /*
         * Increase the GOAL ATTEMPT score for Team A by 1 point.
         */
        public void addGoalAttemptForTeamA(View v) {
            ShotOnGoalForTeamA=ShotOnGoalForTeamA + 1;
            displayForTeamA(ShotOnGoalForTeamA);
        }
        /**
         * Increase the GOAL ATTEMPT score for Team B by 1 point.
         */
        public void addGoalAttemptForTeamB(View v) {
            ShotOnGoalForTeamB=ShotOnGoalForTeamB + 3;
            displayForTeamB(ShotOnGoalForTeamB);
        }
        /**
         * *This will (hopefully) reset the values of the scores of both teams to 0
         */
        public void resetScore(View v) {
            scoreTeamA=0;
            scoreTeamB=0;
            FoulForTeamA = 0;
            FoulForTeamB = 0;
            ShotOnGoalForTeamA = 0;
            ShotOnGoalForTeamB = 0;
            displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
            displayForTeamB(scoreTeamB);
            displayFoulScoreForTeamA(FoulForTeamA);
            displayFoulScoreForTeamB(FoulForTeamB);
            displayGoalAttemptForTeamA(ShotOnGoalForTeamA);
            displayFoulScoreForTeamB(ShotOnGoalForTeamB);

        }
    }
```

>

>
  ***I will add the actual error now:***

```
    01-07 11:47:14.420 26936-26936/com.example.android.soccercounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.android.soccercounter, PID: 26936
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.soccercounter/com.example.android.soccercounter.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.soccercounter.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.soccercounter.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.soccercounter-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2809)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

> ***AND NOW THE XML FILE:***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Team A" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="56sp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
                android:text="Add a Goal!"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fouls comitted :"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_foul_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="26sp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addFoulForTeamA"
                android:text="Add a foul"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Goal Attempts:"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_goal_attempt_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="26sp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addShotOnGoalForTeamA"
                android:text="Add a Shot on Goal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

        </View>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Team B" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="56sp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addOneForTeamB"
                android:text="Add a Goal!"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fouls comitted :"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_foul_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="26sp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addFoulForTeamB"
                android:text="Add a foul"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Goal Attempts:"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_goal_attempt_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="26sp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="addShotOnGoalForTeamB"
                android:text="Add a Shot on Goal"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Referee"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Stadium"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:onClick="resetScore"
        android:text="RESET score "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is most probably in the manifest **AndroidManifest.xml**. The class which is set as the main activity, doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think file name provided by you is not searched by it ,so apk file throughs the exception so use filehandler or import the file